# Event Listener for Cycle2 Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, event-listener, cycle2

I am using a jQuery plugin called cycle2 (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) and I want to target a different element when a particular slide is active.

In a nutshell, it is a picture slide show with corresponding images as a nav bar at the bottom. The nav bar images are black and white but when the slide is active for that particular image, I want the nav bar to display in colour.

The cycle slider applies a class called `cycle-slide-active` to the slide that is active, and then removes it once it moves onto the next slide.

I can make it work by using a dirty infinite loop to check the class against the ID it is assigned to, as follows:

```
function checkForChanges() {
    var slide = jQuery('.cycle-slide-active:first').attr('id');
    var active

    if ( slide == s1) {
        active = s1;
    } else if ( slide == s2 ) {
        active = s2;
    } else if ( slide == s3 ) {
        active = s3;
    } else if ( slide == s4 ) {
        active = s4;
    }

    jQuery('.celeb-button').css('opacity', 0);
    jQuery('.celeb-button-'+active).css('opacity', 1);

    setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);
}
```

However, an infinite loop like this I know is wrong, and it also means I can't use a hover effect to bring the colour out as the infinite loop is constantly changing the opacity back to 0.

I want to add an event listener, so that the function is fired on slide cycle, but I cannot seem to target this behaviour.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in event. I am using the feature that permits the initialization of the slideshow without code.

"opts" is a hash that contains quite a few values, to see them you can view the list in the console by using

```
console.log(Object.keys(opts));
```

opts.currSlide gives the index of the slide.

On the original Cycle, you could get the id of the current slide by simply using this.id , unfortunately, this doesn't work in Cycle 2. I also had trouble getting the current id reliably when using the index of the slide, so I used prev.id to get the id of the previous slide and just set up my conditions accordingly

If you are initializing your slideshow programatically, change the class name ".cycle-slideshow" to your id. This is a separate command. I run this just prior to the slide loading, you can also use 'cycle-after' if you want it to run right after the slide loads.

Your code would look something like this:

```
$( '.cycle-slideshow' ).on( 'cycle-before', function( event, opts, prev, next) {
    if ( prev.id == s1) {//you are on the second slide
        active = s2;
    } else if ( prev.id == s2 ) {
        active = s3;
    } else if ( prev.id == s3 ) {
        active = s4;
    } else if ( prev.id == s4 ) {
        active = s1;
    }
});
```